# python docker how to print return code of the script to know if the test script passed or failed

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

Basically I have 2 issues:

1. It is not printing the logs when I try to run using python docker apis, but it prints using docker run?
2. How to get the return code of the script which I run inside the container?

This is what I have tried:

```
import docker
dockerClient = docker.from_env()
print dockerClient.containers.run(image='centos7.5', command='./pmml2luastatic')
```

Answer (score 1):

1) According to [documentation](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html) function run does not print, but returns stdout and stderr

> The container logs, either STDOUT, STDERR, or both, depending on the value of the stdout and stderr arguments.
>   STDOUT and STDERR may be read only if either json-file or journald logging driver used. Thus, if you are using none of these drivers, a None object is returned instead. [See the Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#) documentation for full details.

For show log, I suggest considering run container in subprocess instead of running via API.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("docker run --rm -i centos7.5 ./pmml2luastatic", shell=True)
```

2) This way also will allow you to catch return code via CompletedProcess object

```py
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run("docker run --rm -i centos7.5 ./pmml2luastatic", shell=True)

if result.returncode != 0:
   print("Error")
```

I will consider using API for communication with a remote machine.
If you anyway will use API for running container then use `stream` param.

> stream (bool) – If true and detach is false, return a log generator instead of a string. Ignored if detach is true. Default: False.

Comment: thanks, this below worked


detach=True
for log in container.logs(stream=True): print log

Comment: Your welcome. Mark my post as an answer to the question :).