# How to pipe stdout from docker-run in dockerpy

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

When I run my docker image normally like so

```
docker run -v ..... {DOCKER_IMAGE}
```

I get my log in the terminal as expected. But running like so:

```
docker_client = docker.from_env()
container  = docker_client.containers.run(DOCKER_IMAGE, None, environment=[f'foo={self.profile}'], 
volumes={...,}, auto_remove=True, stderr=True, stdout=True)
# No logs show up
```

Seems to suppress logs. How can I get the log output while it's running? Can I stream the docker container run?

I can do this

```
docker_client.containers.run(.... detach=True)
for line in container.logs(stream=True): 
    print(line)
```

But this loses whether it's a debug/info/warning/error

Comment: Have you tried specifying `detach=False`?

Comment: @alan.elkin yeah if I set detach=False it just waits for termination and then containers.logs will have everything. But I need to stream logs as they come out. And as I understand, by default it's detach=False, I can set detach=True and iterate the logs after.

Comment: In the `detach=True` case, the fucntion `print` would print exact logs what container generates(depends on the application in container, what app log, it'd be all) when running, even stopping. What do u exactly mean 'losing debug/info/warning/error'? Is this your self-defined logging level in python file?

Answer (score 0):

What about setting `stream=True`?

Haven't tested it, but in the [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#stream) it says:

> `stream` (bool) – If true and `detach` is false, return a log generator
>   instead of a string. Ignored if detach is true. Default: `False`.

Please, give it a try and tell me how it went.

Update:
After googling for "stream", I found a similar question that may help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722489/python-docker-how-to-print-return-code-of-the-script-to-know-if-the-test-script)

Comment: My question includes the example of it using stream=True, it allows me to iterate over each log entry whilst detached but it doesn't retain what kind of log it is, error, info, debug, etc.

Comment: I'm explicitly trying to avoid shelling out to run the docker image.

Comment: In your OP, you're using `stream=True` in the `logs` method, but not in the `run` method (alongside `detach=False`)

Answer (score -1):

```
docker logs -f <CONTAINER>
```

See this page: https://success.docker.com/article/view-realtime-container-logging

Comment: I need to stream the logoutput after running the run command through dockerpy.